# DNS domain name format for a valid DNS query

Tags: dns

I was told that in order for my DNS query to work, I have to convert the domain name. 
 i.e. `rit.edu` -> `rit3edu` ; `www.google.com` to `3www6google3com`

I cannot find where in the RFC https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt that this is discussed, as I even tried performing a find. In my packets that I send to the DNS server. I keep the '.' domain name, and I am getting 'unknown extended label'. I cannot find any helpful threads either. I found a function on GitHub, but there is no discussion on the format. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What?? Don't link a resource if does NOT contain a reference to your question / problem. Copy in, however, any code that you used for which you are getting the response including shell commands. Tag OS, programming language.

Comment: Use Wireshark to capture a packet sent by your application and compare it to a valid one.

Comment: @markful RFC1035 is the specification that deals with DNS wire format, which seem what the OP is talking about, even if his question is not clear at all.

Comment: "I was told" ? By whom, in what context, about what application ? Your question is not clear. As @Blender said, you can always use a dump of a packet to understand what is happening.

Comment: Sorry. I was told by my instructor. when I consulted him about my DNS 
 query being  called a malformed packet by wireshark.  I did find out how this is done. Each label is preceded by the number of characters, in that label, so rit.edu, when being sent as a dns query, should be in the form, 3rit3edu. I didn't find this in the RFC, but I did deduce this from a dump, so thanks Blender.

Comment: I would advise against creating and parsing DNS packets "by hand".  Use some good library instead.  The DNS protocol isn't as simple as it may look at first, and there are various corner cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to this:
http://www.keyboardbanger.com/dns-message-format-name-compression/#Data_label

And in RFC1035 you attached:

```
4.1.2. Question section format  

QNAME   
    a domain name represented as a sequence of labels, where
    each label consists of a length octet followed by that
    number of octets.  The domain name terminates with the
    zero length octet for the null label of the root....
```

Answer (score 1):

In a DNS query, each label of the domain name should be preceded by a number that indicates length of the label. So if `facebook.com` is the question, the actual qname in the DNS query should be `8facebook3com`.

Comment: It is in fact even `8facebook3com0` (if there is no compression), with the final `0` denoting the terminal root.